# Curl comes back with the correct response, Browser is getting back null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs

Here is the issue, `curl` is coming back with the correct response 
 `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8080/rbuilder
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 1067
{"rScriptName":"CollegePlan"," .............}`

However, using ReactJS, browser is coming back empty.

`componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/rbuilder', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      processData: false,
      contentType: "application/json",
      cache: false,
      accept: "application/json"
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log('GET response', res);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }`

However, what I have noticed, in the "Network" tab, is that `rbuilder` appears twice in timeline and the second has correct "response".
What is issue with my fetch ?

Comment: Have you tried '//localhost:8080/rbuilder' instead of the full url.

Comment: @MariaSaavedra 

I am getting response ...... {"rScriptName":"CollegePlan"," .............}

Comment: when you say it comes empty, do you mean that "res" is undefined?

Comment: @QoP body is empty - `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one step.

In order to get your response body, you'll have to use one of these methods depending what you want

**response.text()** - yields the response text as String

**response.json()** - yields the result of JSON.parse(responseText)

**response.blob()** - yields a Blob

**response.arrayBuffer()** - yields an ArrayBuffer

**response.formData()** - yields FormData that can be forwarded to another request

Let's say you want a json, you should do

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/rbuilder', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      processData: false,
      contentType: "application/json",
      cache: false,
      accept: "application/json"
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((body) => {
         console.log(body);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //whatever
    });
}
```

[fetch documentation](https://github.com/github/fetch#json)

Comment: I have added `console.log('GET response', res);` and unfortunately, I am still getting `body:null` in the Chrome console.

Comment: did you check the code in my answer? res shouldn't have a body.